# Passing IntVar() values from one window to another in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to pass a value which is stored under an IntVar from one window to another using controller. But the problem is that the value doesnt update itself.

```
class DSS(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}

    for F in [App, Optimize]:

        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    self.show_frame(App)
def show_frame(self, cont, extras):
    print "show frame"
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    extras.update(extras)
    print str(cont)
    frame.tkraise()

def return_frame(self, cont):
    return self.frames[cont]
```

This is the controller class. And I am posting the lines responsible for the transfer since the rest of the code is too long.

```
radio_btn = tk.Radiobutton(self.kernel_frame, text=txt, variable=self.v, command=lambda: self.import_kernel(), value=val)
  radio_btn.grid(row=row_no, column=1, sticky='w')
```

This is from where I am sending the value of `v`

And this is where I atry to access it.

```
class Optimize(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, master, controller, extras):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack()
    app = controller.return_frame(App)
   # self.v = app.v

    tk.Label(container, text=app.v.get()).pack()
    tk.Button(container, text="Back", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(App, {})).pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getvar method, example :

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# var tkinter are globals in tkinter and are accessible everywhere
var = tk.IntVar()

var.set(123456789)

my_label = tk.Label(root)
my_label.pack()

# Now you can access to your var with its name and getvar method
# _name return the identifier in tkinter, PY_VAR0, PY_VAR1, etc.
my_label['text'] = my_label.getvar(var._name)

# But you can specify your own name for your vars tkinter
my_var =  tk.StringVar(my_label, '', 'my_var' ) # (master, value, name)
my_var.set('blabla')

my_blabla_label = tk.Label(root, text=root.getvar('my_var')).pack()

root.mainloop()
```